# while working on yolov5 algorithm I am training the dataset the train.py file in in the yolov5 folder is not finding

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, object-detection, yolov5

!python train.py --img 415 --batch 16 --epochs 30 --data dataset.yaml --weights yolov5s.pt --cache
after writing this coded it is showing the error
python: can't open file 'train': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you cd to correct directory~
If you are using colab, run this command @cd yolov5

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we cannot use the method @cd yolov5 . But %cd yolov5 works now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).